# Pass props from child to parent without re-rendreing all children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to make a sudoku web app, It consists from a parent component which renders all blocks. Even though every child keeps its own state with the current value inside (all that player could change) I have to update the complete array. It looks something like this

```
const playerTable = [
  [0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9, 5, 0, 0],
  [7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 2, 4],
  [0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 8, 2, 6, 9],
  [1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3],
  [0, 8, 2, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0],
  [9, 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 5],
  [0, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
  [4, 6, 5, 0, 2, 1, 9, 0, 7],
]
```

My idea was to pass the position and new value when state in cube changes and then parent updates the playerTable

`playerTable[row][col] = newVal`

The problem is all children are re-rendered on any change of state from child to parent, which would be about 36 re-renders.

Is there a way to optimize this or should I leave it like that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have the same state both in the parent and in children?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I think we misunderstood each other, every block has a state of its own value, and every time it changes value it updates the state in parent, every time state in parent updates it gets which position and value it should change in the playerTable. It does work as expected except it re-renders all children, and only 1 changed its value.

Comment: So you have duplicated state which should be the case. I would consider using ref instead of state in the parent. You can have `useRerender` hook in every child that will be called onclick

Comment: Ok, so it won't work, you have to have the state in the parent

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Never heard of such hook, I will look into it. Thanks for advice.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-greider-n8x8l4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @KonradLinkowski That should solve it. Once again thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Speaking from my knowledge of React...**

If your parent component **must** hold the entire array in its state, whenever that state is updated, **all child components will re-render, no matter what**. This is a key part of the React diffing algorithm for the virtual DOM.

If you want to make your renders more efficient, then I would say you need to segment and lower your component state, or turn that parent component array state into just data logic that isn't tied to state and re-renders.

Ultimately though, especially with React, I would only bother optimising render cycles if your application is screaming for that optimisation. If your app performs well, then you probably shouldn't waste the time.

Comment: It doesn't reaaally need it, but would probably be posted on heroku, I am just trying really hard to optimise it as best as possible. Thank you for your answer

Comment: If you are really trying to tackle render optimisation, then you will need to ask a much more specific question with all relevant source code, detailed context, and clear requirements. There are many resources online going over the React optimisation and the best practices around it, so I'm sure you will gain more clarity on the subject this way.